# SharePoint 2013 SQL Reporting Services 2014 500 error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, internal-server-error

We have a 3 server farm: 2 WFE, 1 App. SharePoint Enterprise license

The App server has the SQL 2014 reporting services integrated SharePoint with the add in installed.  The WFEs all have the Add in installed.  I've run the:

```
Install-SPRSService
Install-SPRSServiceProxy
```

commands on both WFEs and APP server. (The service is not running on the WFEs, Should it be?)

I installed the Service Application.  When I go to manage the service application, I get the error:

```
Something went wrong, the server returned (500) internal server error
```

The following is the ULS Log of the event:

> WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress:
>   'http://ApplicationServer:32843/91362f8835d04903ac3a703a64a8ae54/ReportingWebService.svc'
>   Channel:
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.IReportServiceManagement'
>   Action:
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2011/06/01/ReportServer/Management/GetSystemProperties'
>   MessageId: 'urn:uuid:a1e5f804-4819-4dc5-ad17-1595d14a2212' Application
>   error when access
>   /_admin/ReportServer/ReportingServicesSystemSettings.aspx, Error=The
>   remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) Getting Error Message for Exception
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type
>   of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder,
>   be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented
>   properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '      IIS 8.5 Detailed
>   Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error     System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     Server
>   stack trace:      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.IReportServiceManagement.GetSystemProperties(ICollection`1
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePointSharedService.ProxyHelper.<>c__DisplayClass9.<GetSystemProperties>b__8(IReportServiceManagement
>   mchannel)     at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.ProxyHelper.DoManagementChannelCall(Action`1
>   caller)     at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.UI.ReportingServicesSystemSettings.get_SystemProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.UI.ReportingServicesSystemSettings.LoadSettings()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.UI.ReportingServicesSystemSettings.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing [SQL 2012 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43340) solved the Problem.

- note that it will only update the below 2 shared features with size
  of around 200mb and do lots of other background tasks of registering
  components,cleanup and SharePoint service reset
- note that farm will be down at the end for about a few minutes
- at first because i have installed the 44MB Microsoft® SQL Server®
  2012 SP1 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft® SharePoint 
  ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35583)), I thought that it is patched, but because the main SSRS-Sharepoint Mode was installed without service pack , it was the root cause i think
- SSRS native service does not need to be installed ad no service will be seen in Services section after you successfully completed it.

  [image]
- do not attempt to install the addin or service on all servers, only one WFE is enough.
- check the main guide [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx) although it is not mentioning patching explicitly, it is absolutely essential
- check that you have all the SSRS aspx files in below path

  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\
- Also note the below final Webpart screenshot in Sharepoint 2013 simple page

[image]